# Laravel to a Json object and Relationships Eloquent

Tags: json, database, laravel, api

I need return JSON Objects to my API.
I have some models but i can't get the relationships done.

**Carga Table**

```
CargaId as PK
Carga_Date
Carga_Description
```

**Movements Table**

```
MovimCod as PK
CargaArtic
MovCargaId as FK
Mov Prov
```

**Carga model**

```
public function GetMovements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Movements', 'MovimCargaId','CargaId');
    }
```

**Movements model**

```
public function GetCarga()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Carga','MovimCargaId','CargaId');
    }
```

The Return is like this

```
[
{"CargaId":11936,
"Carga_Date":"2020-05-27",
"get_movements":[]}
]
```

What I need is JSON Objects, something like this...

```
[
{"CargaId":11936,
 "Carga_Date":"2020-05-27",
"get_movements":
    [
        {
        MovimCod = 1
        CargaArtic = Fernet
        MovCargaId =11936
        Mov Prov =Salta
        },
        {
        MovimCod = 2
        CargaArtic = Coca-Cola
        MovCargaId =11936
        Mov Prov = Tucuman
        }
    ]
}
]
```

When i copy the code to Visual Studio
i need to paste like JSON code with the diferent objects

Answer (score 0):

1. You may still have the relationships wrong if it is returning null objects.
2. The JSON you sugested is not a valid JSON format.

Comment: Hola Daniela! Podrias hacer el favor de ayudarme. Como podria hacer entonces para devolver JSON con los objetos y  sus relaciones?

Comment: el retorno que tienes ya es un JSON, si quieres retornarlo como recurso puedes usar JSONResource, creando un controlador de recursos como explica en la [documentacion](https://styde.net/laravel-6-doc-eloquent-recursos-api/), yo veo que el problema es que la relación te sigue retornando un null en lugar de los movimientos, ¿te sale algun error en los logs al respecto?

Comment: Lo que veo es que debería retornar un arreglo de objetos tipo Movimientos en la respuesta, pero sigue retornando nulo, ¿ya intentaste usar hasOne en el movimiento en lugar de hasMany en la MCarga?

Comment: Que genia Daniela! Gracias por el dato. Voy a trabajar mejor usando simplemente los modelos por separado. Si intente probar el hasOne segun la documentacion, pero sin resultados. Te sigo en Twetter abrazo